# ImageJ scale bar: manually changing one of the values set by a macro while leaving the others as is

Tags: imagej, fiji, imagej-macro

I have a set of macros that allow me to select the magnification of images taken with a microscope, set the scale and add a scale bar with predefined appearance settings.

These macros look like this and are stored in a file called "StartupMacros.txt" in the macros directory of ImageJ:

```
macro "Scale_Leica_010x_whitebg [1]" {
    run("Set Scale...", "distance=3021 known=1000 unit=µm global");
    run("Scale Bar...", "width=500 height=39 thickness=10 font=70 color=Gray background=None location=[Lower Left] horizontal bold overlay");
}

macro "Scale_Leica_020x_whitebg [2]" {
    run("Set Scale...", "distance=4260 known=700 unit=µm global");
    run("Scale Bar...", "width=200 height=39 thickness=10 font=70 color=Gray background=None location=[Lower Left] horizontal bold overlay");
}
```

Sometimes I need to change the appearance of the scale bar depending on the image (e.g. the position of the scale).
However, when I go to the Analyze > Tools > Scale Bar menu, all the settings are reset to their default values.
So if I only want to change the position of the scale bar, I also have to change all the other appearance values (colour, font size, ...).
I would expect that when I open this menu, the values predefined by the macro would already be pre-coded in the corresponding fields, so that I only need to change the value of the position, for example.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: For this to work "Scale Bar"-parameters must be extracted from the individual image which appears being near to impossible. Even if it were possible, the parameters must be inserted to the corresponding plugin, which would be a problem in itself that requires fundamental changes of the Java code.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. The scale bar parameters are provided in the macro.

Comment: How should the parameters from the macro come to the plugin? As I wrote, these are different worlds and although it is in principle possible, it would require modifications of the ImageJ Java-code.